# Call Contains() method in LINQ to Entities Expression on a type other than String

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I am trying to implement searching/filtering in a grid that allows the user to create filter conditions that involve a column, an operation, and a value.

Example: Column1 Contains "somevalue"

The following code works fine when the chosen column contains string types:

```
case WhereOperation.Contains:
    Expression condition = Expression.Call(
       memberAccess, //memberAccess is a MemberExpression of the property bound to the column.
       typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
       Expression.Constant(value.ToString())); // value is what we are checking to see if the column contains.
    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
    break;
```

However, when the property the column is bound to is not of type string (i.e. an Int), this fails because the type `Int` does not have a "Contains" method. How can I first get the `ToString()` value of memberAccess before calling "Contains" on it?

Note 1: The type of the property that "memberAccess" represents is unknown at compile time.
Note 2: The lambda expression ends up being used in a LINQ 2 entities query which cannot explicitly handle `ToString()`. (See what I tried below)

This is one solution I tried but it fails at the time of the LINQ expression evaluation because LINQ 2 entities doesn't support `ToString()`:

```
case WhereOperation.Contains:
    Expression stringValue = Expression.Call(memberAccess,
       typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"));
    Expression condition = Expression.Call(
       stringValue, 
       typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
       Expression.Constant(value.ToString()));
    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
    break;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah... you cant use ToString in Linq to Entities, because of security reasons. Can't remember where i read it. It is suported in Linq2Sql though.
But there is SqlFunctions.StringConvert that you can use.

I made simple extension for you:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AddContains<T>(this LambdaExpression selector, string value)
    {
        var mi = typeof (string).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Contains" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1);


        var body = selector.GetBody().AsString();
        var x = Expression.Call(body, mi, Expression.Constant(value));

        LambdaExpression e = Expression.Lambda(x, selector.Parameters.ToArray());
        return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)e;
    }

    public static Expression GetBody(this LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        Expression body;
        if (expression.Body is UnaryExpression)
            body = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand;
        else
            body = expression.Body;

        return body;
    }

    public static Expression AsString(this Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression.Type == typeof (string))
            return expression;

        MethodInfo toString = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "StringConvert" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1 && m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(double?));
        var cast = Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(double?));
        return Expression.Call(toString, cast);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
        IQueryable<Foo> seed = ...;
        Expression<Func<Foo, int>> selector = x => x.Id;
        var expression = selector.AddContains<Foo>("3");
        seed.Where(expression);
```

Comment: Trying to adapt this to my code so it fits my usage but I think there's an issue with the length being passed to AsString(). It needs to be the length of the selector's value, not the value we are passing as an argument to Contains(). I'm not sure how to get the length of the value of the selector.

Comment: I haven't abandoned this question. I've just had some other priorities come up so I haven't had a chance to return to this code. Should get to it on Tuesday and will accept answer or comment more as appropriate. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Sorry it took so long but I was finally able to return to this problem and your solution worked great. Thanks!

Comment: +1: @maxlego when one starts learning expression trees, all this stuff does not look that simple at all...Thank you a lot. Your answer is helpful indeed